# How to paralelize processing of dataframe in apache spark with combination over a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm looking a solution to build an aggregation with all combination of a column.  For example , I have for a data frame as below:

```
val df = Seq(("A", 1),  ("B", 2),  ("C", 3),  ("A", 4),  ("B", 5)).toDF("id", "value")

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  A|    1|
|  B|    2|
|  C|    3|
|  A|    4|
|  B|    5|
+---+-----+
```

And looking an aggregation for all combination over the column "id". Here below I found a solution, but this cannot use the parallelism of Spark, works only on driver node or only on a single executor. Is there any better solution in order to get rid of the for loop?

```
import spark.implicits._;

val list =df.select($"id").distinct().orderBy($"id").as[String].collect();
val combinations = (1 to list.length flatMap (x => list.combinations(x))) filter(_.length >1)

val schema = StructType(
  StructField("indexvalue", IntegerType, true) ::
  StructField("segment", StringType, true) :: Nil)
var initialDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema)

for (x <- combinations) {
       initialDF = initialDF.union(df.filter($"id".isin(x: _*))
          .agg(expr("sum(value)").as("indexvalue"))
          .withColumn("segment",lit(x.mkString("+"))))

 }

 initialDF.show()

+----------+-------+
|indexvalue|segment|
+----------+-------+
|        12|    A+B|
|         8|    A+C|
|        10|    B+C|
|        15|  A+B+C|
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: what is the usecase for this?. The scenario doesn't fit the MapReduce model, even if we apply it, it will use the least parallelism (i.e just one ) and so what you have now is good.

Comment: Use case is about calculating aggregated values for all segment combinations and insert to a db for API queries. API allows filters such as A+B or A+B+C

Comment: It does not fit the MR paradigm, SPARK is more flexible but the 0114 person is correct, cannot really distribute such a problem. It's expansion not reduction in this case.